Why is UPF 50+ the maximum UPF rating achievable?
I read on https://www.solbari.com/blogs/solbari-blog/what-is-the-maximum-upf-rating (mirror):

UPF 50+ is the maximum UPF rating achievable and it denotes that only up to 2% (or 1/50th) of UV radiation can penetrate fabrics with this rating. Australia was the first country in the world to formally rate fabrics for sun protection in the 1990s.

Why is UPF 50+ the maximum UPF rating achievable?

Up to 2% is a very small amount and it does include up to 1% and even non UV penetration.
Clothes that guarantee to let less UV through will likely fall into the waterproof category, where all seems are taped and no holes of sewing are allowed at all, this is clothing you will not want to wear in sunny conditions.
I guess the authorities that have described the UPF 50+ rank have been sensible and understood that higher guarantees are practically impossible.
For those few people that require 100 % protection other measures should be taken. Like adding several different kinds of protection, including sunscreen creams and even staying indoors when the sun is out.

In the mid-80's there certainly were products claiming SPF 100. My vague recollection was the FDA decided that 50 was 'good enough' and the cost-benefit of 100 did not compute for them. My friends doing high-altitude glacier travel were not happy at all since 50 just didn't cut it there between less UV absorption by the atmosphere and lots of reflection off the white snow/ice.

@JonCuster for SPF (suncream) even more than for UPF (clothing)  the variation  due to application/stretch becomes very significant at high protection levels, while the actual blocking becomes harder to measure.  Thus even if you can be confident in the data at such high levels, you can't be confident in the protection.  Also the blocking is measured over a spectral range; some damage can occur outside this range and if the edges of the stopband are sharp that will dominate.  All of which is to say that "claiming" is probably a good choice of word

Plenty of ways of making clothing could have untaped seams but no through-holes (e.g. lined jackets - imagine a leather jacket for example) and wouldn't have to be made of waterproof fabric.  But your "can't guarantee >50" conclusion seems right
